# Spring bom usage error

Tags: java, maven-3, mdc

Previous implementation of `MDC` used

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
    <version>${spring.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Now am planning to use

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.spring.platform</groupId>
    <artifactId>platform-bom</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.1.RELEASE</version>
    <type>pom</type>
    <scope>import</scope>
</dependency>
```

But the code which was working previously :

```
private final Map<?, ?> parentContext; // initialized in constructor
MDC.setContextMap(parentContext);
```

The above line is giving the error :

```
The method setContextMap(Map<String,String>) in the type MDC is not applicable for the arguments (Map<capture#5-of ?,capture#6-of ?>)
```

Kindly suggest.

Comment: You still need the dependency. The import should go in the `dependencyManagmenet` section. See http://platform.spring.io/platform/ Also `MDC` has nothing to do with `spring-webmvc` it is a log4j (or slf4j) class probably.

Comment: The BOM dependency is there in `DependencyManagement` section only. I added `log4j-over-slf4j` dependency also still the same error.

Comment: Do a `mvn dependency:tree` and check the differences.

Comment: No difference its just that the dependency was separate when I explicitly add if not exists with some other dependency.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to upgrade the `MDC` dependency has upgraded and the method signature has changed. So I basically changed the implementation of the variable from

```
private final Map<?, ?> parentContext;
```

to

```
private final Map<String, String> parentContext;
```

Problem solved.